# htaccess settings to allow access to special non-drupal page

Tags: redirection, .htaccess

I have a properly working Drupal 6 site, at the webroot of my server, which can be accessed by www.mysite.com or by mysite.com. I have some special html files (not part of Drupal) that can be currently accessed by going to mysite.com/special and that works fine.

I would prefer that people just go to special.mysite.com to get to the html files in that directory (instead of mysite.com/special).   I just had the DNS set up so that special.mysite.com now points to the webroot, and Drupal currently handles it the same as www.mysite.com.

However, I would like it if people coming to special.mysite.com arrive at the index file within the "special" folder on mysite.com. I bet I can do something to the .htaccess file that Drupal uses in the webroot directory - but I don't know what? Any advice? Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add in your .htaccess.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^special.mysite.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mysite\.com\/special" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: find in your Drupal htaccess the place to put this after RewriteEngine on. Remember that little bad changes in your .htaccess will pull down your site.

Comment: That worked OH SO perfectly. Thanks a ton for your help.